# PHP Session not working as expected

Tags: php, session

I am having problems getting PHP sessions to work correctly.  I have the following two pages as a test. I would expect sess2.php to output 'bing' but it isn't doing.

sess1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['usr'] = 'bing';
echo '<a href="sess2.php">go</a>';
```

sess2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['usr'];
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try var_dump($_SESSION['usr']); instead echo. So you can see even if the value is null.

Comment: You have cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: I don't think cookies must be enabled to manipulate server-side session variables

Comment: @SubinThomas yes the value is null when I do a var_dump

Comment: @Chris yes, cookies are enabled

Comment: Please, check [all these configs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) on your **php.ini** file.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['usr']); put this in the sess1.php file and see session is getting set or not @PeterAstbury

Comment: @SubinThomas he already said it returns null.

Comment: @AlanMachado Not in forwarded page. In the same page session set done.. in sess1.php file..

Comment: I think maybe can be a session store path , maybe it can be bad writte permisions or  not defined , try to do echo session_save_path() , if not null then check  if the the folder have write permissions

Comment: @AlanMachado session variables all look fairly standard to me... https://www.dropbox.com/s/74i7ccd4pq340j5/phpsession.PNG?dl=0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200612/session-variables-are-not-persisting-between-page-loads describes all the possibilities in session @PeterAstbury

Comment: has the var/lib/php/session folder writte permisions?

Comment: @JoaquinJavi I thought it did - apache has full permissions on the folder - however when, just to test, I gave full 777 permissions to that folder everything worked as expected - so apparently 'apache' isn't the user that needs the permissions.  As I'm running Plesk php is run by psacln so that was the user that needed permissions - NOT apache as I had thought. 

Thanks!  If you want to post this as an answer rather than a comment then I'll mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: Ok i will now , and firstly apologize me i didn't read deeply in you question and using mobile while i'm in transit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

has the var/lib/php/session folder writte permisions?

Sometimes the user / group executing apache are not the same as the root  or your owner user/group, that's depending on specific built in configuration.

Try to chmod 777 to your session storage path , you can perform it doing session_save_path()  to see the specific folder or look in your phpinfo()

Comment: can you reword this an an answer rather than as a followup query? That would be much more helpful to this and other people reading this question on SO. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @JoaquinJavi this helped!  I had permissions set on that folder but for the wrong user - I had assumed that the permissions were needed by apache but php wasn't being run by apache - I changed ownership of the folder to the user which php runs as and all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify files like this to see where the problem is:

sess1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['usr'] = 'bing';
echo '<a href="sess2.php">go</a>';
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, true) . '</pre>'
```

sess2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, true) . '</pre>'
```

If you see an empty `$_SESSION` at `sess1.php` then the problem with opening and/or setting session itself; if `sess1.php` is fine, but `sess2.php` has empty `$_SESSION` then something wrong with passing session across requests (e.g. disabled cookies). Either way this will give you a clue on where the problem is and figure out solution from there.

Comment: Thanks - the session variables weren't being stored as the folder that stores them on the server had the permissions set incorrectly.  All sorted now.