# Session variables are not persisting between page loads

Tags: php, session

I try to create a session to be available for PHP pages.

But it is not working.

**Test1.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["current_id"] = 7 ;

echo "Current id : " .  $_SESSION['current_id'] . "</br>" ;
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "' . session_save_path() . '" is not writable for PHP!'; }
else {
    echo 'Session path "' . session_save_path() . '" is Writable for PHP!'; } 
echo("</br>");    
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

**Result**:

> Current id : 7
>   Session path "/var/lib/php5" is Writable for PHP!
>       /home/ubuntu/workspace/CRF/main1.php:58: array(1) { 'current_id' => string(1) "7" }

**Tets2.php**

```
session_start();
echo "Current id : " .  $_SESSION['current_id'] . "</br>" ;
echo("</br>");    
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

**Result**:

> Current id : /home/ubuntu/workspace/CRF/workflow.php:108: array(0) { }

Any Ideas?

Comment: That code should give you some serious syntax errors. You're not closing the php tag after `$_SESSION["current_id"] = 7 ;` while opening a new one two lines down. _Tip:_ If you have a block of code, have _one_ open php tag and then _one_ close tag after all the code, don't open and close it per command.

Comment: Thank you. Off course the block is closed. It's lost when I copy code. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you justbaron . It's not a duplicate question. I put <?php session_start(); ?> on the first line of the pages.

Comment: You should give more information since _not working_ is very general.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for your comment, not working is mean session variable not available in any pages except where it was initialized.

Comment: turn on [error logging on your page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587515/how-to-display-php-errors-in-code-output). What does that tell you?

Comment: @justbaron no, not a duplicate of that question. Read the qustions!

Comment: @Konstantin111 have you checked all the replies and potential issues [raised here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200612/session-variables-are-not-persisting-between-page-loads)?